# How to link a anchor point to a new page with the exact position

Tags: html, css, anchor

Hey there Im trying to link a anchor point to a new page(Home Page) with the exact position

When I navigate on the home page it is working fine

[image: Home Page]

As soon as I navigate from a other page to the home page for instance (About Us) it cuts of the word

[image: About Us]

Any clues why its doing that?

Comment: share your code

Answer (score 2):

Try this,
place following code in top of About Us section

```
 <a name="section"></a>
```

And make your link some thing like following

```
<a href="http://www.yoursite.com/about_us#section">About Us</a>
```

It will navigate to that page and scroll to specified position

Comment: Hey  chathurabuddi it doesnt work the wording is still cutting off

Comment: If you can share your code, I can figure out whats the problem

Comment: <section id="services">
 <div class="container">
         <a name="services"></a>
 <h2><b>Services</b></h2>
 <div data-appear-top-offset="-200" data-animated="fadeInUp<div>
 We are bull distributes that cater for big company's and for the public.We do delivery's on time every time. We buy bulk and safe your money.</div> <br>
                            <img src="images/delivery.jpg" width="100%"><br><br><br>
                           
    </div>
   </div>
  </section>

Comment: <li class="scroll_btn"><a href="index.html#services">Services</a></li>